# Error while using copy command to copy files in subfolders

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, file-transfer

I'm using the folliwing command to copy all files of the same extension from a folder and all its subfolders to a new destination:

```
for /R "f:\" %f in (\*.mp3) do copy %f "C:\Documents and Settings\AL\Desktop\mp3\"
```

It is necessary to say that some files have spaces and the command works great for files without spaces. I've added quotation marks to the directories but it didn't work.

Is there some kind of instruction to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
FOR /R "f:\" %f in (*.mp3) do copy "%f" "C:\Documents and Settings\AL\Desktop\mp3\"
```

I've omitted the backslash before your wildcard `(*.mp3)` instead of `(\*.mp3)` and put double quotes around the filename as argument of the copy command: `copy "%f"`.

Comment: It worked fantastic.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.